# Is $\delta : \mathcal{S}(\mathbf{R}) \to \mathbf{C}$ continuous with usual seminorm?

Tags: distribution-theory

I am thinking again the accepted answer which is found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/611988/discontinuity-of-dirac-delta-distribution):

> When viewing $\delta: \mathbf{S} \to \mathbf{R}$ (linear and
>   continuous with respect to the usual  semi-norms on the Schwartz-space
>   – or similar on the space of test  functions), it makes sense to say
>   that $\delta$ is continuous.

and changing the spaces.

Assume that viewing $\delta : \mathcal{S}(\mathbf{R}) \to \mathbf{C}$ with respect to the usual semi-norms on the Schwartz space. 
**Is usual seminorm enough to keep $\delta$ continuous wit new selection of domain and range?**

I think the usual seminorm is a function on a vector space $V$, denoted $\lVert v \rVert$, such that the following conditions hold for all $v$ and $w$ in $V$, and any scalar $c$.

1. $\lVert v \rVert \geq 0$
2. $\lVert c v \rVert = |c| \lVert v \rVert$, and
3. $\lVert v + w \rVert \leq \lVert v \rVert + \lVert w \rVert$.

It is possible for $\lVert v \rVert = 0$ for nonzero $v$.
The functional $\lVert f \rVert = |f(0)|$ for continuous functions is a seminorm which is not a norm.

Comment: Why not start by writing down what the "usual seminorms" are?

Comment: @GEdgar I added what I think is the usual seminorm. I think it is the usual definition given, for instance, in Wolfram.

Comment: No, to study continuity of the "delta function" $\delta$, you will need to write down the seminorms (there are many of them) that define the topology on *this particular* space $\mathcal S(\mathbb R)$.  From your response, it seems you will need to read about $\mathcal S$, won't you?

Comment: What do you mean by changing the domain?

Comment: @YiorgosS.Smyrlis I mean by changing the domain or better changing the spaces in the mapping, only that changing mapping from $\delta : S \to \mathbf R$ to $\delta : S(\mathbf R) \to \mathbf C$.

Comment: @Masi Nothing changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\mathbb R$ be the real line.  Let $\mathcal S(\mathbb R)$ be the set of (complex-valued) Schwarz functions, that is $g \in \mathcal S(\mathbb R)$ iff $g$ is infinitely differentiable and all derivatives of $g$ are rapidly decreasing at $\pm \infty$.  For nonnegative integers $n,m$, seminorms are defined by
$$
\|g\|_{n,m} = \sup\left\{|x^n g^{(m)}(x)|\;:\; x \in \mathbb R\right\}
\tag{*}$$
Define functional $\delta : \mathcal S(\mathbb R) \to \mathbb C$ by
$$
\delta(g) = g(0).
$$
TO SHOW: $\delta$ is continuous, in the topology defined by the seminorms (*).

PROOF.  Let $\epsilon > 0$ be given, and let $f \in \mathcal S(\mathbb R)$.  To show that $\delta$ is continuous at $f$, it suffices to show: there exist $n,m \in \mathbb N$ and $\delta > 0$ so that, for all $g \in \mathcal S(\mathbb R)$,
$$
\text{if } \quad \|g - f\|_{n,m} < \delta \quad\text{then}\quad
|\delta(g) - \delta(f)|<\epsilon.
$$
In fact, we can take $n=0, m=0, \delta=\epsilon$.  If $\|g-f\|_{0,0} < \epsilon$, then $\sup \{|g(x)-f(x)| : x \in \mathbb R\} < \epsilon$, so in particular $|g(0)-f(0)|<\epsilon$, which is to say $|\delta(g) - \delta(f)|< \epsilon$.

Comment: Clear answer! This proves also the mapping $\delta : \mathcal S \to \mathbf R$ or better written, I think, $\delta : \mathcal S (\mathbf R) \to \mathbf R$.

Comment: In notation $\mathcal S(\mathbf R)$, I took $\mathbf R$ to be the domain of the functions.  Did you intend that is be the range set?

Comment: No no. I was referring to the old mapping of old thread where we did not specify the domain. But I think this proves also the thing for the range $\mathbf R$, since complex numbers are only an extension of real-numbers.

Comment: **Can we say now that Dirac delta distribution is smooth if we define differentiation by duality as follows?** $\delta' \not= 0$, and it is defined on elements of $\mathscr{S}$ as $\delta'(\varphi) = -\varphi'(0)$.

Comment: Why not try to prove that this $\delta'$ is continuous yourself? ... Use the model provided here, but you may need to choose different values for $n,m$.