# Is delta distribution continuous and differentiable with dual space norm?

Tags: continuity, normed-spaces, distribution-theory

I know that delta distribution $\delta : \mathcal S (\mathbf R) \to \mathbf C$ is continuous with usual [seminorm](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/615096/does-delta-distribution-remain-continuous-with-respect-to-quasinorm) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/611988/discontinuity-of-dirac-delta-distribution).

I am interested in its continuity with dual-space $H^{-1}(\Omega)$ of $H_{0}^{1}(\Omega)$, which I think is based on $L_2(I)$ norm in its denominator:

\begin{equation}
\lVert f \rVert_{L_{2}(\Omega)} = \sup_{
\substack{v \in L_{2}(\Omega) \\ v \neq 0 } }
\frac{
|(f,v)|}{
\lVert v \rVert_{L_{2}(\Omega)}}
\end{equation}

We define the space of *square integrable functions* on $I$:
\begin{equation}
L_{2}(I) = \{ v: v \text{ is defined on } I \text{ and } \int_{I} v^{2} dx < \infty \}.
\end{equation}

I want also that the delta distribution is differentiable, which do by duality.

**Is delta distribution continuous and differentiable with dual space norm?**

Comment: Why don't you accept the non-continuity with respect to any  $L^2$-norm as I already pointed out [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/615096/does-delta-distribution-remain-continuous-with-respect-to-quasinorm). I vote to close this question as a duplicate to the linked question.

Comment: @Vobo Can you, please, prove it rigorously that delta distribution is non-continuous with respect to $L^{2}$ norm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\varphi$ be a test function (i.e. $C^\infty$ with compact support) with $\varphi(0)=1$ and set $\varphi_n(x)=\varphi(nx)$. Then $\varphi_n$ is a test function and you have using the substitution $nx\mapsto t$
$$
||\varphi_n||_{L^2} = \Bigl( \int |\varphi(nx)|^2 dx \Bigr)^\frac{1}{2} = \Bigl(\frac{1}{n} \int |\varphi(t)|^2 dt \Bigr)^\frac{1}{2}\longrightarrow 0 \,\text{ as }\ n\to\infty.
$$
On the other hand you have $\delta(\varphi_n) = \varphi_n(0) = \varphi(0) = 1$ for every $n$. This proves the non-continuity of $\delta$ with respect to $L^2$-norm.